# Count rows in excel

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, range

I am trying to have a for loop iterate over the populated section of column b on an excel spreadsheet.  I am almost positive that I have the code correct but for some reason it gives me an invalid qualifier error at the `.Row` point in the code below. I am really unsure where I went wrong and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Set rng1 = Range("B2")
Set rng2 = Range("B2").End(xlDown)


For i = 1 To Sheet2.Range(rng1, rng2).Row.Count
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there:

```
.Rows.Count
```

**Update**

Try this:

```
Dim lLastRow As Long

lLastRow = Sheet2.Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 1 To lLastRow

    Debug.Print Sheet2.Cells(i, 1)

Next
```

Comment: Thanks! I made that change but now it is saying the method of the range object failed...

Comment: I've updated my answer to give you a different way of doing this. You can manipulate the cells by referring to them as shown after debug.print

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do this, here is one:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Rowcount()

Dim i& , LastRow&
Dim Sh as Worksheet

Set Sh= thisworkbook.sheets("Sheet2")

with Sh
    'Set rng1 = .Range("B2")
    Set rng2 = .Range("B2").End(xlDown) 'this method gives the first empty cell, wich is not always the last Row , works if NO empty cell

    lastRow = rng2.row ' the real last row with some empty cells is LastRow= .cells(.rows.count,2).end(xlup).row

    For i = 1 To LastRow

        ...'do stuff
        'Debug.Print .Cells(i, 1).value2
    Next i

End With 'Sh
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You can also find the last row of populated data using

```
Sub lastRowTest()

    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    'edit: Patrick Lepelletier also mentions this method in his post
    lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row    'finds the first non-empty cell, starting from the bottom

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        'do stuff on cells
    Next i

End Sub
```